# The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition Windows server 2008 r2, Event ID: 109 Task Category: (103)

Tags: windows, server

I have downloaded VM from AWS and it's getting shut down often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your windows license might expired, if so windows is going shuts down every one hour

Comment: also applies for Windows server 2016

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is actual for Evaluation versions of Windows/
for not activated instances it does not shut down